# How can I view the generated WSDL for a wcf function

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service.  I built from an xsd file from another department. All it generated was classes, which I inturn modified to match our "standards".  I need to see if the wsdl for that function matches the xsd, well actually the wsdl for one of the inputs, matches what they gave us.

```
http://localhost:26535/EDeliveryOrderSvc.svc?wsdl
```

shows the wsdl for the entire service.  the section for my function:

```
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateOrUpdateOSSOrdersFromEntityInput">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://[redacted]/EDeliveryOrderSvc/CreateOrUpdateOSSOrdersFromEntityInput" style="document" /> 
 <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

doesn't tell me anything about the input parameters.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see a line in the wsdl that says:

http://localhost:26535/EDeliveryOrderSvc.svc?xsd=xsd2

or some such, go there to see the schema info.